# What is wrong with my custom checkbox component? It should update state with an array of items, but instead it just sets the last checkbox value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following custom checkbox component:

```
<script setup>
    defineProps({
        modelValue: Array,
        options: Array,
    })
    defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<template>
    <div v-for="option in options" v-bind:key="option">
        <input type="checkbox" :id="option" :value="option" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
        <label :for="option">{{ option }}</label>
    </div>
</template>
```

which I then use like this:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import CheckboxInput from './CheckboxInput.vue';

    const user = ref({
        name: '',
        contactPreference: [],
    })

    const checkboxOptions = ref(['By email', 'By phone', 'Via SMS'])
</script>

<template>
    <div class="user-input-container">
        <div class="user-input">
            <p>Contact Preference</p>
            <CheckboxInput v-model="user.contactPreference" :options="checkboxOptions"></CheckboxInput>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

However, when I check any textbox, the value of user.contactPreference becomes the string value of the checkbox instead of an array with the values of all checked checkboxes.

What happens is that `user.contactPreference === 'By email'` when I expect it to be `['By email']`. Also checking more than once checkboxe just overwrites the string with the last value that was checked.

Comment: `$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)` would result in `user.contactPreference` being a single value rather than array - you need to fix your `$emit('update:modelValue'` to emit the `options` array filtered by the corresponding checkbox's being checked/unchecked

Comment: Vue 3 makes everything easier. You don't need to use the - Props-Emits. Just in Parent make provide('user ', user ) and in Checkbox - const user = inject('user ')
 and on @input make with "user" all you want.
https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you give me an example please? I'm having some trouble figuring that out.